# Clearing a specific figure in MatPlotLib

Tags: python, matplotlib

In MatPlotLib, I can use:

```
plt.gcf().clear()
```

To clear the contents of the current figure.

But suppose I have two figures, created with:

```
fig1 = plt.figure(1)
fig2 = plt.figure(2)
```

How can I clear a specific figure based on its number?

Answer (score 3):

`.clear()` is a method of the figure class. It doesn't matter if you obtain an instance of `matplotlib.figure.Figure` via `plt.gcf()` or via the variable you store it in. Therefore

```
fig1.clear()
```

will clear the figure stored in `fig1`.

Of course you can also directly use the call to `plt.figure()` to clear that figure,

```
plt.figure(1).clear()
```